# Urban Airship Push Notifications not working with Production Certificate

Tags: iphone, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, urbanairship.com

I am developing an iOS App with Push Notifications. I am able to successfully test the push notifications using the Developer APN Certificate but it does not work with the Production APN Certificate.

I have ensured that the profiles in the iOS Developer Portal (adhoc / distribution) are generated after Push Notification is enabled for the APP ID and have taken care to use the correct UA_KEY and UA_SECRET in AppDelegate.m.

Can anybody please provide insights on as to what could be the possible reason(s) why Push notifications are failing using Production Certificate but working fine with Development Certificate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally seemed to have sorted this out and posting back here in hope that it may help.

The key point which helped me to identify the problem was to turn on 'Debugging' in the UA Console to see the details errors. (This was actually the suggestion provided by their support team)

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you have figured that out by now. Anyway, I think the problem caused by not including your **Production** `UA_Key` and `UA_Secret` in your `UAConfig` file. It's better to follow up with the sample they provide in their [Resources page](http://urbanairship.com/resources/) as you can't go wrong with their sample.